# pythonic way to get first element of multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a simple pythonic way to get the first element of a numpy array no matter it's dimension.  For example:

For `[1,2,3,4]` that would be 1

For `[[3,2,4],[4,5,6]]` it would be 3

Is there a simple, pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: `arr.ravel()[0]`, basically flatten it and access the first item.

Comment: @cs95. That was my first thought, but it could create a copy of the whole thing if the array is not contiguous

Comment: `arr.flat[0]` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

Using a direct index:

```
arr[(0,) * arr.ndim]
```

The commas in a normal index expression make a tuple. You can pass in a manually-constructed tuple as well.

You can get the same result from [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
arr[unravel_index(0, arr.shape)]
```

On the other hand, using the very tempting [`arr.ravel[0]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) is not always safe. `ravel` will generally return a view, but if your array is non-contiguous, it will make a copy of the entire thing.

A relatively cheap solution is

```
arr.flat[0]
```

[`flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) is an indexable iterator. It will not copy your data.

Comment: `np.unravel_index(0, arr.shape)` is another way of creating that n-d index.

Comment: @hpaulj. Thanks. Added. I also found `flat`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `.item`, for example:

```
a = np.identity(3)
a.item(0)
# 1.0
```

But note that unlike regular indexing `.item` strives to return a native Python object, so for example an `np.uint8` will be returned as plain int.

If that's acceptable this method seems a bit faster than other methods:

```
timeit(lambda:a.flat[0])
# 0.3602013469208032
timeit(lambda:a[a.ndim*(0,)])
# 0.3502263119444251
timeit(lambda:a.item(0))
# 0.2366882530041039
```